wordpress logged_in_ cookie : python function to check authenticity of wordpress logged_in_[hash] cookie
Context
I'm working on an integration project with a wordpress website. I have ssh access to the wordpress server. I'm using fastapi (python framework for web APIs) for the backend of my project. The app I'm developing will be accessible in a sub-domain of the wordpress site to benefit from wordpress authentication via auth logged_in_[hash] cookies.
Problem
To run my tests, I authenticated to wordpress to retrieve the logged_in_[hash] session cookie.
Based on :
wp_hash()
generate_auth_cookie()
wp_salt()
Code extract from wordpress :
function wp_generate_auth_cookie( $user_id, $expiration, $scheme = 'auth', $token = '' ) {
$user = get_userdata( $user_id );
if ( ! $user ) {
    return '';
}
if ( ! $token ) {
    $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );
    $token   = $manager->create( $expiration );
}
$pass_frag = substr( $user->user_pass, 8, 4 );
$key = wp_hash( $user->user_login . '|' . $pass_frag . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token, $scheme );

// If ext/hash is not present, compat.php's hash_hmac() does not support sha256.
$algo = function_exists( 'hash' ) ? 'sha256' : 'sha1';
$hash = hash_hmac( $algo, $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token, $key );

$cookie = $user->user_login . '|' . $expiration . '|' . $token . '|' . $hash;

I try to create hmac like wordpress and if my generated hmac == hmac_from_cookie it's win.
def wp_hash(data: str) -> str:
    """Replicate WordPress's wp_hash function with MD5 HMAC."""
    salt = f"{WP_AUTH_KEY}{WP_LOGGED_IN_SALT}"
    return hmac.new(salt.encode(), data.encode(), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()

def validate_wp_cookie(cookie_value: str) -> bool:

    cookie_value = urllib.parse.unquote(cookie_value)  # %7C -> |

    parts = cookie_value.split("|")
    if len(parts) != 4:
        print("Invalid cookie format.")
        return False

    username, expiration, token, expected_hmac = parts

    user_pass = get_user_by_username(username).get("user_pass")

    pass_frag = user_pass[8:12]

    key = wp_hash(f"{username}|{pass_frag}|{expiration}|{token}")

    hash_hmac = hmac.new(
        key.encode(), f"{username}|{expiration}|{token}".encode(), hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

    cookie = f"{username}|{expiration}|{token}|{hash_hmac}"

    cookie = urllib.parse.quote(cookie)

    print("expected_hmac : ", expected_hmac)
    print("hash_hmac : ", hash_hmac)

    return hmac.compare_digest(cookie, cookie_value)

cookie values are the same for username | expiration | token but different for hmac
I've tried with sha1 and sha256, only 256 gives me the right length, so I guess 256 is used.
So I tried different keys for wp_hash:
def wp_hash(data: str, scheme: str = "auth") -> str:
    """Replicate WordPress's wp_hash function with MD5 HMAC."""
    salt = f"{WP_AUTH_KEY}" # or f"{WP_SECURE_AUTH_KEY}" or f"{WP_AUTH_KEY}{WP_LOGGED_IN_SALT}"
    return hmac.new(salt.encode(), data.encode(), hashlib.md5).hexdigest()


But nothing works.
Do you have any idea how I could get the same hmac? Or if it's possible to check the authenticity of the logged_in_[hash] auth cookie more simply?
As a reminder: I have ssh access to the machine that hosts wordpress, and I don't know if there's any link but on wordpress the plugins used for membership management is paid membership pro.

you say you guess it's sha256 but why are you note sure ? and compare the hashed values on your code with the same values generated by wordpress in php.

I said I thought it was sha256 because of this:
$algo = function_exists( 'hash' ) ? sha256' : 'sha1' ;```
But when I compare the output length when I use sha1 or sha256, it's clearly the same as sha256, so I'm pretty sure it's sha256.

If I understand well, cookie format is :
<user_login>%7C%7C%7C<hash_mac> 
user_login = find in wp_usermeta 
expiration = find in wp_usermeta.meta_key = session_tokens =>
meta_value = s:64:"some_token";a:4:{s:10:"expiration";i:someexp;s:2:"ip";s:36:"someipv6";s:2:"ua";s:78:"Mozilla...";s:5:"login";i:somedate;}

But token in database is differents than token in cookie. I find this function in wordpress :
hash_token( $token ) 
So I try to hash session token from database with sha1 and sha256 but it still different. So I'm not sure I've understood everything about the wordpress token system.

finally, I'm going to use a wordpress plugin as an Oauth authentication server. It'll be safer and simpler.
